# How to use GLX from Java?

Tags: opengl, java

I am trying to use Clojure to create an opengl window under Linux. Is there a tutorial on how to use GLX and X Window directly. I'd rather learn how to do this directly, which I already know how under Windows with win32 sdk, instead of relying on a wrapper.

Comment: Asking for tutorials isn't the best use of this site. Instead, ask a question specifically abut the step you're having trouble with. This means you'll have to try it first and this may even solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to call directly into something like [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/). Learning new things is fun! :-)